# How to filter pending and processing orders at the same time

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, filter, order-grid

I want to be able to filter orders "pending" and "processing" at the same time (like the last option on the image).

How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: Is this your custom grid?

Comment: yes, but the grid may vary to different users. so it's irrelevant.

Comment: Grid created using ui-component? If yes then add `status` column code in question.

Comment: use field to filter on order status collection on this option in your block then render your grid on the collection

Answer (score 0):

You can get processing and pending order from order collection like this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create();
$orderCollection = $orderCollectionFactory
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('processing','pending')))
                ->setOrder('created_at','desc');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orderCollection->getData());
echo "</pre>";
```

Try to use factory method instead of Object Manager.